# undefined is not a function for server.listen

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to define a `nodejs` module as following:

```
"use strict";
const
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util'),
    net = require('net'),
    // server constructor
    NetWatcherServer = function(handler) {
        net.createServer(handler);
    };

// expose module methods
exports.NetWatcherServer = NetWatcherServer;
exports.createServer = function(handler){
    let server = new NetWatcherServer(handler);
    server.listen(5432, function() {
        console.log('Listening for subscribers...');
    });
    // should i be doing anything like:
    // util.inherits(server, ?????);
    // to simulate inheritance? what should be the ?????
    return server;
};
```

However when I try to call it with:

```
"use strict";
const netWatcher = require('./net-watcher-server.js');
netWatcher.createServer(function(connection) {
    console.log('test');
});
```

Then I get:

> ```
> server.listen(5432, function() {
>            ^
> TypeError: undefined is not a function
> ```

I thihnk this means it does not identify the function `listen` on `server` I do see that `nodejs` provides a utility to provide the prototype (to simulate inheritance) but i'm not sure how i should be using in the `exports.createServer` I think i should be adding something like:

```
util.inherits(server, ?????);
```

but even if that is correct i don't know what to put in place of the `?????`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return the server instance from your function. Simple fix:

```
NetWatcherServer = function(handler) {
    return net.createServer(handler);
};
```

Comment: `so the result is undefined` OP's calling `new NetWatcherServer`, which will create an object. It's not `server` that's undefined, it's `server.listen` because it was never defined.

Comment: Sorry, english isn't my first language... @zzzzBov

Answer (score 1):

`new NetWatcherServer(handler);` creates a new instance of your `NetWatcherServer` function. You don't need this instance, you just need the server that it generates.

Just call the function:

```
let server = NetWatcherServer(handler);
```

and make sure the function returns a value:

```
NetWatcherServer = function(handler) {
    return net.createServer(handler);
};
```